# C++: Cleanup memory leak of 3rd party library?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I have some code that calls a 3rd party library (which I do not have the source code for).

A 'getHandle()' function in this library allocates some memory and returns a DWORD_PTR to it, but there is a bug in the library's 'freeHandle(DWORD_PTR p)' function and the memory is never deallocated. Because I don't have the source code for this library, I have no idea how the DWORD_PTR is constructed.

Is there any way I can track the memory that is allocated by 'getHandle()' and free it up myself?

Comment: No - Why do that? - Get them to fix it unless you have misunderstood the documentation

Comment: It's a leak not a user error, and the developer is a huge corporation known for ignoring user requests. This is also a time critical issue, so I can't wait 12 months if they decide to fix it in their next release. I guess it's off to plan B....

Comment: Is the leak so big? Is it identified as a false leak (static data for example). Can you live with it? Apart from that you cannot do much.

Comment: @Tyson Before doing anything, have you actually verified it is a leak?   To verify, did you allocate and *immediately* attempt to deallocate?  If not, then there is no clear proof that there is a leak.  I know of know company, large or small, that would not address leakage issues in their library or app in a timely fashion.

Comment: Yes, it's a confirmed leak. When I try deallocating immediately after allocating, the memory is not released. The function I'm using is from a very old part of a very big library, that isn't often used by developers...so that would explain why it went unseen and why they're in no hurry to fix it (I have contacted them about it and have had no response).

Comment: @EdHeal It's not static data and the memory leak is pretty big. It occurs when caching bitmaps to RAM, so within a few seconds the memory usage climbs to many GBs, since my program deals with caching hires image sequences.